# Diophantine equation $546\cdot p+546\cdot q=1001\cdot r$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

$546\cdot p+546\cdot q=1001\cdot r$

$p,q$ odd primes, r positive integer.

are there infinitely many solutions?

And what if r is a Catalan number?

Answer (score 3):

By Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions, there are infinitely many odd primes $p$ and $q$ whose sum is divisible by $11$. For such primes $p$ and $q$, you get a solution by taking $r=6(p+q)/11$. So there are infinitely many solutions, and all solutions are of this shape. For Catalan numbers the problem seems to be out of reach.